# Valueof hidden field is not being set with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I am adding a rating system to an existing JavaScript popup and I am having trouble getting the value of the star that was clicked to the hidden field to be submitted to the form.

My code is as follows:

```
echo 'Please rate the quality of this transcript:<br/>';
echo '<div id="stars">';
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
     echo '<img alt="' . $i . '" src="' . site_url('img/off.png') . '" id="' . $i . '" onclick="submitRating(' . $i . ');">';
}
echo '</div>';
echo '<input type="hidden" id="rating" name="rating" value="">';
```

The JavaScript that gets called onclick is:

```
function submitRating(id) {
   for (i = 1; i <= id; i++) {
       document.getElementById(i).src = '<?php echo site_url('img/on.png'); ?>';
   }
   document.getElementById('submit').style.display = 'block';
   document.getElementById('rating').value = id.toInt();
}
```

When I echo out what has been sent to the function to process the form, it shows rating as blank. I tried using `document.getElementById('rating').value = new Number(id);` and `document.getElementById('rating').value = 'id';` and `document.getElementById('rating').value = id;` but that didn't work either.

If I add an `alert(id);`, the correct value gets echoed out.

Is this because the field is hidden? I tried making it a text field and hiding it, but that didn't work either.

**EDIT:** Am I doing this correctly or do I need to use jQuery or AJAX or something along those lines?

Comment: what is id.toInt()? just assign id to value of rating

Comment: What about `document.getElementById('rating').value = id` without trying to convert it to a number?

Comment: or use parsInt(id) instead of toInt

Comment: I tried the `parseInt(id)` and the `document.getElementById('rating').value = id` and neither of those worked.

Comment: Just checking the obvious, but is this star rating block *inside* the `<form>`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much fiddling with the code, I moved the `'<input type="hidden" name="rating" id="rating">' +` line up to above the form and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to use a number as an identifier for a DOM element.

```
// Not possible
<div id="123"></div>
```

```
// Possible
<div id="element_123"></div>
```

The specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Comment: I didn't know that. I will try it and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this doesn't change the value that's being passed to the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to the lines before the value of hidden field set, comment those lines or put setting hidden field line in top of submitRating function and test the code

```
 function submitRating(id) {
   document.getElementById('rating').value = id;
   alert(document.getElementById('rating').value);
   //for (i = 1; i <= id; i++) {
       //document.getElementById(i).src = '<?php echo site_url('img/on.png'); //?>';
   //}
   //document.getElementById('submit').style.display = 'block';

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did move the line up and the alert shows the correct value, but when the form is submitted, it's still blank.